# How to assign access policy after creation of key vault

Tags: azure-functions, azure-keyvault, pulumi

I am using Azure-native provider and have the following situation:

1. A Function App which needs secret URI in AppSettings
2. A Key Vault which holds the secret and also grants Managed Identity of Function App access to read it.

How can I create it using pulumi? It is chicken or the egg situation.
Pulumi azure-native doesn't support managing access policy separately like azure classic provider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, it's not supported today in the Azure Native provider. The feature is tracked [here](https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi-azure-native/issues/594).

For now, you can use the resource from the classic provider for this particular use case. You can mix-and-match two providers in the same program as you wish.

Comment: Is this still the case a year later?

Comment: Yes, it's still the case